# How do I deal with a type that should be initialized as an empty object before http requests?

Tags: typescript

So I have a defined type

```
export type User = {
  id: string
  [prop: string]: any
}
```

and I need that this type be able to store a empty object as well.

But if I try something like that:

```
const user: User = {}
```

I get the error

> Property 'id' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'User'.ts(2741)

I need to set the `user` as an empty object, because it's only populated after an HTTP request.

I know I can make use of:

```
const user: User = {} as User
```

But I wonder if this is the only way, do I need to type `{} as User` every time I set the user variable as an empty object? Or there are better ways to do it?

How do I deal with these scenarios?

Comment: Have you tried `{id?: string; [prop: string]: any}` where `id` is optional?

Answer (score 1):

We want to use a union type which combines an empty object and another interface. Now simple choice says you should use `type Final = IFace |{}` but that would be wrong.

Actually empty object type acts weirdly in TypeScript where you can use it to represent a lot of things. Read [this](https://www.totaltypescript.com/the-empty-object-type-in-typescript).

Quoting from the article:

> The empty object type in TypeScript doesn't really behave as you expect. It doesn't represent "any object". Instead, it represents any value that isn't null or undefined.

Hence that is why if you do something like:

```
export type IncorrectUserType = {
  id: string
  [prop: string]: any
} | {};

const x1: IncorrectUserType = {};
const y1: IncorrectUserType = 'x'; //This will not throw an error
```

We do not want that. And that is why we create our own type for empty object:

```
type EmptyObj = Record<PropertyKey, never>;

export type User = {
  id: string
  [prop: string]: any
} | EmptyObj;


const x2: User = {};
const y2: User = 'x'; //Throws an error
```

Here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=1&pln=10&pc=1#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBJAdgY1jEHOAVQGcQYAVVdAXgQG9gEEBLAEwC4FS4ZWsAc2YIA2hBhQI3XvyEBdbgEMsyYAF8EAH0bqA3MGB4svBGACM3bHhgEiZCtTQJ6DfUagnEyS5lz5CEnIqGhcEAHIwcINDFGcAUQBbCBQAeQAjACswgCVCWHYAHgAFSTR4ZABpEGQAGgQsEAA3CgA+GPBoeCRQhxgwphYOGT4BYRZxMpG5QUUEFTVNHSSU5AzMmI8vMwAmbj6B92NTZD2EA-pI6MNgIA) for you to try out.

Here is a Github [thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47486) discussing the same issue. You might find that there is no REAL way to type an empty object in TS, and every approach might have some flaw

Answer (score 0):

You can use a union with an empty object.

```js
export type User = {
  id: string
  [prop: string]: any
} | {}
```

Beware it will have an effect on your existing usages as it will not know if it is now the "complete" object or empty one.  Consider leaving your `User` type as is and creating an `OptionalUser` or something version and discriminating it to `User` across some domain boundary.

Comment: `{}` accepts all objects, `AnyObject | {}` will collapse into `{}`. Use `Record<string,never>` for empty object

Answer (score 0):

While an "empty object" might seem like a reasonable choice for an initial type, it ends up not being very usable. A more practical choice might be an object which has values that are simply not known, and that can be represented by a type whose keys are `PropertyKey` and values are `unknown`:

```ts
type UnknownObject = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>
```

Using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) can be convenient, but it doesn't provide the same kind of strong guarantees that validating your data does. TypeScript supports [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) of type information through its [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis). It also offers a useful feature which allows you to validate that a value conforms to the expected type — by using a function to do the work needed to verify that: these functions are called [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) and the return type is called a *type predicate*.

You can use this pattern in your code to begin with an unknown object and then validate that it is the expected type before using those properties. Here's an example:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgazgewO5wPICMBWEDGwUAvFAEoHIBOAJgDwAKVykVoA0hCADRQCuiFOgB8AbgBQ40JFgBnCFRJQA3uKhQAljQBcUWcCoa4AcwnqaAQ2ARdcPgFssCs1Aj2LGgDa79hkxIBfCXEAMwFCDWQ4TVkYeSo6ABVXAA9rOBpZWEE0TFwCYGEACncQJziFXUSASl1S8viYqGSAMjkFFTUoAHpuqABBQj4LT08QKAA3Ea0raAgJhXGwCzYoZBCoYAALaCnPPggAcizfPiGqaB2L7S6L4D4qaKKu9WkIdah6iAqqADotEjEUgAIl8RmMwKgLRaL024HeGy+P1+lmsgJBdkcCkh0Nhbw+SPivzcHk86KgoIM4OBXWqgUk+Ci+n48V08CQuWweEISmUQUkvQGRFkyHs0DAyCMwF422gyHyPKsLI6GiywIlYD4nlmNCgFhC1kUFmiAAlEokGFALgBHA76YGAMgJxIKAMKisVwIhROWKezUOUbWVQELIUZocFQTxGCBZYDIPQQaAWKA0DQhEIKCCeq0xrVEfWGybTVGROA3PhEgEgixYfDAiQVhQo2ZKACMABZ2wBWADMAA4uwA2AAMw4bRJJXiUwPcbBAAAF7PgQmNfoz7PWBX0AEIQEMXFng3ggZB8KD4Y1FqOo6DbJUaIhbCxZJxZz7IVMhDQQXUWfCM2gIzjKATweVJIEIKxS1kG40ygIpVR+IpGyoapqk6dRBQATVPc9L1kfUIDGZVNh2cCCh-K87SgK4bC6Rk4BFTwIF+TxkGMIpgQwBAZS2VUmmTFDgTpSR1BQ-4aBcdQem6AA9AB+LpxJvKTMLkxSxIndwvFUmSFKUokRTFDBZSoJgWAUUBdN6fSAlcTx5AwmSoG3PgiBQR9MxudQGKYli2I44EADlkHzZUqGE4JNKbLRrPUgymxU2E9I08LiW0zw4v06K-iMiATKuczWCs5KbMUgJxCAA)

```ts
type UnknownObject = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>;

type User = {
  id: string;
  date: number;
  email: string;
};

function isUser<T extends UnknownObject>(maybeUser: T): maybeUser is T & User {
  // Actually validate every part of the value's structure here:
  return (
    typeof maybeUser.id === "string" &&
    typeof maybeUser.date === "number" &&
    typeof maybeUser.email === "string"
  );
}

const user: UnknownObject = {};

// At some point, the object at user is "populated after an HTTP request"…
// Comment one or more of the following lines to see a different result after validation:
user.id = "abc";
user.date = 1445385600;
user.email = "marty@mcfly.com";

// Before using, you can validate that it has been modified according to your expectations:
if (isUser(user)) {
  // You can safely use the expected values here:
  console.log("Ok, this is a user");

  user.id;
     //^? (property) id: string
  user.date;
     //^? (property) date: number
  user.email;
     //^? (property) email: string
  user.someOtherProperty;
     //^? unknown
} else {
  // But not here:
  console.log("Not a user");

  user.id;
     //^? unknown
  user.date;
     //^? unknown
  user.email;
     //^? unknown
  user.someOtherProperty;
     //^? unknown
}
```

See also: [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) and [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types).

Answer (score 0):

```
export type User = {
  id: string
} | Record<string,never>
```

Dont use type like

```
export type User = {
  id: string
  [prop: string]: any
}
```

not only because `any` is bad, but because when you change `any` to other type:
[image]